# Convert a 2D array into 3D array repeating existing values

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have an array of shape (360,480) containing values from 1 to 11,

```
 Array([[ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
   [ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
   [ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
   ...,
   [ 4,  4,  4, ..., 11, 11, 11],
   [ 4,  4,  4, ..., 11, 11, 11],
   [ 4,  4,  4, ..., 11, 11, 11]])
```

How could I reshape this array into an array of shape (360,480,3) in a way that

```
np.all(array[:,:,0]==array[:,:,1])
```

and

```
np.all(array[:,:,0]==array[:,:,2])
```

are both True?
The expected outcome should be

```
array([[[ 1,  1,  1],
    [ 1,  1,  1],
    [ 1,  1,  1],
    ...,
    [ 1,  1,  1],
    [ 1,  1,  1],
    [ 1,  1,  1]],

   [[ 4,  4,  4],
    [ 4,  4,  4],
    [ 4,  4,  4],
    ...,
    [11, 11, 11],
    [11, 11, 11],
    [11, 11, 11]],

   [[ 4,  4,  4],
    [ 4,  4,  4],
    [ 4,  4,  4],
    ...,
    [11, 11, 11],
    [11, 11, 11],
    [11, 11, 11]]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use numpy.repeat function

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html

```
array3d = np.repeat(array2d[:, :, None], repeats=3, axis=2)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! It works as I wanted it to!